# Get time to close, instead of days

Tags: lightning, formula, reporting, datetime, date

I'm trying to get a column added to a Salesforce report for case management. Using the SF Lightning experience.

There are 2 fields available currently:

- Date/Time Opened
- Date/Time Closed

These fields have a date and a time separated by comma. For example: 4/21/2023, 11:00 AM

I need a field added to this report where it is only calculating the time and not the date. For example:

- Date/Time Opened = 4/21/2023, 11:00 AM
- Date/Time Closed = 4/23/2023, 2:05 PM
- Hours to Close = 51H 5M

This "Hours to Close" field is what I am trying to add to the report.
I tried to achieve this by adding a Row Level Formula and searching online on how to use the different functions but am coming up empty.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVTACiCxhZM shows how to do this for days. For hours, divide by 24.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply subtract one date/time/datetime from another (e.g. `MyDateTime__c - MyOtherDateTime__c`)

This'll give you a result like `2.5376` where:

- The `2` (or rather, everything to the left of the decimal point) is the number of whole days between the dates
- The `.5376` is the number of seconds (represented as a fraction) in a partially elapsed day if your two operands aren't *exactly* x days apart

86,400 seconds in a day would mean 0.5376 = 46,448 seconds (approximately)
which with some simple math you can turn that into hours/minutes/seconds (12 hours, 54 minutes, 8 seconds)

While this is possible to do in a formula *in theory*, I imagine it would be a pretty painful formula to write (and it might go over the formula compile size limit). This is something I'd do in Apex (and store in a dedicated field that you can bring into your report), where we have variables and thus wouldn't need to repeat the hours calculation again to get the minutes calculated (and then both the hours and minutes calculations to get the seconds calculated). A flow might be able to do this as well.

+edit:
Ok, so Salesforce's example date/time formulas reveals a less painful way to  extract the hours/minutes/seconds.

- Subtract the two datetimes
- multiply by the number of units of the time component in a day (i.e. `* 24` for hours, `* 24 * 60` for minutes, `* 24 * 60 * 60` for seconds)
- modulo {# of units in the next higher unit}

From Salesforce's example

> ```
> IF(
> datetime_1 - datetime_2 > 0 ,
> TEXT( FLOOR( datetime_1 - datetime_2 ) ) & " days "
> & TEXT( FLOOR( MOD( (datetime_1 - datetime_2 ) * 24, 24 ) ) ) & " hours "
> & TEXT( ROUND( MOD( (datetime_1 - datetime_2 ) * 24 * 60, 60 ), 0 ) ) & " minutes",
> ""
> )
> ```

and you'd `FLOOR()` instead of `ROUND()` on the minutes if you wanted to get down to seconds